# Teamcity meta-runner with multiple runners - exiting a runner without failing the build

Tags: powershell, teamcity

OK, so here's a TeamCity meta-runner with 2 separate runners inside. Essentially the first runner will have a bunch of logic in it that determines if a deploy should occur or not.

```
<build-runners>
  <runner name="Step 1" type="jetbrains_powershell">
    <parameters>
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_bitness" value="x86" />
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_execution" value="PS1" />
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_minVersion" value="4.0" />
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_script_code"><![CDATA[

#Bunch of powershell logic here... under some conditions we want nothing deployed

#Now I want to exit the whole build step, not just this single runner
Exit #<- Fails the whole build, not what I want

]"]]></param>
      <param name="jetbrains_powershell_script_mode" value="CODE" />
      <param name="teamcity.step.mode" value="default" />
    </parameters>
  </runner>
  <runner name="Deploy Project" type="octopus.deploy.release">
    <parameters>
      <param name="octopus_additionalcommandlinearguments" value="" />
      <param name="octopus_deployto" value="%Octopus.EnvironmentName%" />
      <param name="octopus_host" value="%system.Octopus-ServerUrl%" />
      <param name="octopus_project_name" value="%ProjectName%" />
      <param name="octopus_releasenumber" value="%ProjectRelease%" />
      <param name="octopus_version" value="3.0+" />
      <param name="octopus_waitfordeployments" value="true" />
      <param name="secure:octopus_apikey" value="123123" />
      <param name="teamcity.step.mode" value="default" />
    </parameters>
  </runner>
</build-runners>
```

What is a way I can exit the whole meta-runner step so it continues just fine with the next build step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from vendor:

"It seems there is no clean way to skip remaining meta-runner steps without affecting build (successful) status. If you do not mind settings build to failed, you can try Execute "If all previous steps finished successfully" in the meta-runner steps to skip."

While the meta-runner feature is quite good in TeamCity, it does have its limitations.